# New to Latex and having trouble

Tags: errors

I am very new to LaTeX. I tried to compile a file and came up with so many error. How do I correct them?

```
% thesis.tex

%=====================================================================
% Read: http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/karkare/iitbthesis/
%    FAQ.txt     for frequently asked quetions
%    Changes.txt for changes
%    README      for more information

%=====================================================================

%=====================================================================
% DOCUMENT STYLE
%=====================================================================
% IITB PhD Thesis format default settings are:
%   12pt, one-sided printing on a4 size paper
\documentclass{iitbthesis}
% For two-sided printing, with Chapter starting on odd-numbered pages,
% use the following line instead:  
%%\documentclass[openright,twoside]{iitbthesis}
%=====================================================================
% OPTIONAL PACKAGES
%=====================================================================
% To include optional packages, use the \usepackage command.
% For e.g., The package epsfig is used to bring in the Encapsulated
%    PostScript figures into the document.
%    The package times is used to change the fonts to Times Roman;
%=====================================================================
\usepackage{txfontsb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{psfig}
\usepackage{epsfig}
%% The amssymb package provides various useful mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\let\iint\relax
\let\iiint\relax
\let\iiiint\relax
\let\idotsint\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{wasysym}
% \usepackage{numcompress}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bbm}    %%% For some special blackboardfonts
\usepackage{enumerate}  %%% For special numbered lists
\usepackage{url}    %%% For typesetting URLs and email ids
\usepackage{psfrag}     %%insert Symbol or formula in xfig file */
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib} %%% For better citations
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{quotchap}
%%%% For better citations
%=====================================================================
%  Single counter for theorems and theorem-like environments:
%=====================================================================
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{assertion}[theorem]{Assertion}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{figger}[theorem]{Figure}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
%=====================================================================
% End of Preamble, start of document
%

\begin{document}

%=====================================================================
% Include the prelude for Title page, abstract, table of contents, etc
% You need to modify it to contain your details
\include{prelude}
%=====================================================================
% Include the technical part of the report
\include{chapter1}             % Chapter 1: Introduction
\include{chapter2}             % Chapter 2: A Short Review of Related Research Works
\include{chapter3}             % Chapter 3: FETLA - Finite element thrust line analysis
\include{chapter4}             % Chapter 4: Thrust line analysis of masonry domes
\include{chapter6}             % Chapter 6: Development of two node element for axisymetric shell
\include{chapter5}            % Chapter 5: Study of different problems in masonry dome
\include{chapter7}             % Chapter 7: Concluding Remarks
\include{chapter8}             % Chapter 8: Concluding Remarks
%=====================================================================
%\renewcommand{\appendixnameI}{\vspace{-40pt}\bf{Appendix I}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix I}
%\begin{appendixnameI}
%\input{appendix}
%\end{appendixnameI}
%\clearpage
%=====================================================================
%\renewcommand{\appendixnameII}{\vspace{-40pt}\bf{Appendix II}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix II}
%%\begin{appendixnameII}
%\input{appendix_ii}
%%\end{appendixnameII}
%\clearpage 
%=====================================================================
%\renewcommand{\appendixnameIII}{\vspace{-40pt}\bf{Appendix III}}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix III}
%%\begin{appendixnameIII}
%\input{appendix_iii}
%%\end{appendixnameIII}
%\clearpage
%=====================================================================
% APPENDIX
%  Appendices, if any, must precede the cited literatures.
%  Appendices shall be numbered in Roman Capitals (e.g. Appendix IV)
\appendix
\include{appendix}          
\include{appendixB}  
\include{appendixC}  
\include{appendixD}  
%=====================================================================
% BIBLIOGRAPHY
%   This should follow the appendices, if any, otherwise summary and
%   conclusions chapter.
% Choose your bibliography style
% plain is the basic style, others include ieeetr, siam, asm, etc
%\bibliographystyle{agsm}
% Add the bib file
%\bibliography{spsw}
%%
%$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{References}
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
%\bibliography{CA,pjg,SBIB/abbrev,SBIB/mped,SBIB/biped,SBIB/qped,SBIB/self}
\bibliography{domeTL}
\clearpage
%$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$
%%
%=====================================================================
\renewcommand{\publications}{\vspace{-40pt}\bf{Publications}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications}
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-60pt}
%\begin{publications}
\input{mypubs}
\clearpage
%=====================================================================
\renewcommand{\acknowledgements}{\vspace{-40pt}\bf{Acknowledgements}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements}
\input{acknowledgements}
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately we cannot help you if you use a special class we do not have.

Comment: If you are new to latex then don't start with a monster document with an usual class. When learning to swim you don't start with crossing the chanel.

Comment: I just want to find out the error, first error i got is "! LaTeX Error: Command \iint already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.557 ...d{\iint}{\DOTSI\protect\MultiIntegral{2}"

Comment: The problem is that you include so many font packages etc. that one cannot be sure from where that comes. Please break your code down to the necessary to reproduce the error (just remove the unnecessary code temporarily) and edit your post accordingly. Best would be you would also switch to a standard class. Then we can help you best.

Comment: See here: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to know how a MWE should be written.

Comment: You can also have a look at [LaTeX for Thesis writing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: You should not load epsfig and probably should not load times, you are loading amsmath twice (the second will be ignored) do not load graphics (it is already loaded by graphicx) do not load psfrag if you are using pdflatex.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a preamble which compiles smoothly:

```
\documentclass{iitbthesis}
% For two-sided printing, with Chapter starting on odd-numbered pages,
% use the following line instead:
%%\documentclass[openright,twoside]{iitbthesis}
%=====================================================================
% OPTIONAL PACKAGES
%=====================================================================
% To include optional packages, use the \usepackage command.
% For e.g., The package epsfig is should not be used any more: `graphicx` does the job.
% The package newtx is used to change the fonts to a Times Roman clone;
%=====================================================================
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} 
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{bbm} %%% For some special blackboardfonts
\usepackage{enumitem} %%% For special numbered lists: more powerful than enumerate 
\usepackage{url} %%% For typesetting URLs and email ids
%\usepackage{psfrag} %%insert Symbol or formula in xfig file */
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[round,sort]{natbib} %%% For better citations
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{quotchap}
%%%% For better citations
%=====================================================================
% Single counter for theorems and theorem-like environments:
%=====================================================================
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{assertion}[theorem]{Assertion}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[theorem]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{figger}[theorem]{Figure}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}
%=====================================================================
% End of Preamble, start of document
```